# Invalid Reference Id : Line.SalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have tried to create sales receipt in quickbook using quickbook api. My most of sales receipt has successfully created at quick book without any issue. But quickbook api throw exception for one order. I have got below error:

```
{
  "Fault": {
    "Error": [
      {
        "Message": "Invalid Reference Id",
        "Detail": "Invalid Reference Id : Line.SalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef",
        "code": "2500",
        "element": "Line.SalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef"
      }
    ],
    "type": "ValidationFault"
  },
  "time": "2017-05-04T03:32:18.942-07:00"
}
```

Below are json that I have tried with API :

```
{  
   "SalesReceiptEx":null,
   "AutoDocNumber":null,
   "CustomerRef":{  
      "name":"Alexander",
      "type":null,
      "value":"325"
   },
   "CustomerMemo":null,
   "BillAddr":{  
      "Id":"1",
      "Line1":"Alexander Kryukov",
      "Line2":"22 Chester Terrace",
      "Line3":"London",
      "Line4":"United Kingdom,GB",
      "Line5":"NW1 4ND",
      "City":null,
      "Country":null,
      "CountryCode":null,
      "CountrySubDivisionCode":null,
      "PostalCode":null,
      "PostalCodeSuffix":null,
      "Lat":null,
      "Long":null,
      "Tag":null,
      "Note":null
   },
   "ShipAddr":{  
      "Id":"2",
      "Line1":"Alexander Kryukov",
      "Line2":"22 Chester Terrace",
      "Line3":null,
      "Line4":null,
      "Line5":null,
      "City":"London",
      "Country":"United Kingdom",
      "CountryCode":null,
      "CountrySubDivisionCode":"GB",
      "PostalCode":"NW1 4ND",
      "PostalCodeSuffix":null,
      "Lat":null,
      "Long":null,
      "Tag":null,
      "Note":null
   },
   "RemitToRef":null,
   "ClassRef":null,
   "SalesTermRef":null,
   "DueDate":null,
   "SalesRepRef":null,
   "PONumber":null,
   "FOB":null,
   "ShipMethodRef":null,
   "ShipDate":null,
   "TrackingNum":null,
   "GlobalTaxCalculation":null,
   "TotalAmt":"136.90000",
   "HomeTotalAmt":null,
   "ApplyTaxAfterDiscount":null,
   "TemplateRef":null,
   "PrintStatus":null,
   "EmailStatus":null,
   "BillEmail":{  
      "Id":null,
      "Address":"sash_300@hotmail.com",
      "Default":null,
      "Tag":null
   },
   "ARAccountRef":null,
   "Balance":null,
   "HomeBalance":null,
   "FinanceCharge":null,
   "PaymentMethodRef":null,
   "PaymentRefNum":null,
   "PaymentType":null,
   "CheckPayment":null,
   "CreditCardPayment":null,
   "DepositToAccountRef":{  
      "name":"Business Bank Account HSBC",
      "type":null,
      "value":58
   },
   "DeliveryInfo":null,
   "DiscountRate":null,
   "DiscountAmt":null,
   "GovtTxnRefIdentifier":null,
   "DocNumber":1163080716,
   "TxnDate":"2017-05-04",
   "DepartmentRef":null,
   "CurrencyRef":null,
   "ExchangeRate":null,
   "PrivateNote":null,
   "TxnStatus":null,
   "LinkedTxn":null,
   "Line":[  
      {  
         "Id":1,
         "LineNum":1,
         "Description":"Flowery Floater Birthday Number",
         "Amount":"43.29167",
         "LinkedTxn":null,
         "DetailType":"SalesItemLineDetail",
         "PaymentLineDetail":null,
         "DiscountLineDetail":null,
         "TaxLineDetail":null,
         "SalesItemLineDetail":{  
            "ServiceDate":null,
            "TaxInclusiveAmt":null,
            "DiscountRate":null,
            "DiscountAmt":null,
            "SalesItemLineDetailEx":null,
            "ItemRef":{  
               "name":"Flowery Floater Birthday Number",
               "type":null,
               "value":"1"
            },
            "ClassRef":null,
            "UnitPrice":"43.29167",
            "RatePercent":null,
            "PriceLevelRef":null,
            "MarkupInfo":null,
            "Qty":"1",
            "UOMRef":null,
            "ItemAccountRef":null,
            "InventorySiteRef":null,
            "TaxCodeRef":{  
               "name":null,
               "type":null,
               "value":2
            }
         },
         "DescriptionLineDetail":null,
         "ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail":null,
         "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail":null,
         "DepositLineDetail":null,
         "PurchaseOrderItemLineDetail":null,
         "ItemReceiptLineDetail":null,
         "JournalEntryLineDetail":null,
         "GroupLineDetail":null,
         "SubTotalLineDetail":null,
         "TDSLineDetail":null,
         "CustomField":null,
         "LineEx":null
      },
      {  
         "Id":2,
         "LineNum":2,
         "Description":"Custom Product",
         "Amount":"37.50000",
         "LinkedTxn":null,
         "DetailType":"SalesItemLineDetail",
         "PaymentLineDetail":null,
         "DiscountLineDetail":null,
         "TaxLineDetail":null,
         "SalesItemLineDetail":{  
            "ServiceDate":null,
            "TaxInclusiveAmt":null,
            "DiscountRate":null,
            "DiscountAmt":null,
            "SalesItemLineDetailEx":null,
            "ItemRef":{  
               "name":"Custom Product",
               "type":null,
               "value":"10"
            },
            "ClassRef":null,
            "UnitPrice":"3.75000",
            "RatePercent":null,
            "PriceLevelRef":null,
            "MarkupInfo":null,
            "Qty":"10",
            "UOMRef":null,
            "ItemAccountRef":null,
            "InventorySiteRef":null,
            "TaxCodeRef":{  
               "name":null,
               "type":null,
               "value":2
            }
         },
         "DescriptionLineDetail":null,
         "ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail":null,
         "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail":null,
         "DepositLineDetail":null,
         "PurchaseOrderItemLineDetail":null,
         "ItemReceiptLineDetail":null,
         "JournalEntryLineDetail":null,
         "GroupLineDetail":null,
         "SubTotalLineDetail":null,
         "TDSLineDetail":null,
         "CustomField":null,
         "LineEx":null
      },
      {  
         "Id":3,
         "LineNum":3,
         "Description":"Additional Delivery Charge",
         "Amount":"30.00000",
         "LinkedTxn":null,
         "DetailType":"SalesItemLineDetail",
         "PaymentLineDetail":null,
         "DiscountLineDetail":null,
         "TaxLineDetail":null,
         "SalesItemLineDetail":{  
            "ServiceDate":null,
            "TaxInclusiveAmt":null,
            "DiscountRate":null,
            "DiscountAmt":null,
            "SalesItemLineDetailEx":null,
            "ItemRef":{  
               "name":"Additional Delivery Charge",
               "type":null,
               "value":"1"
            },
            "ClassRef":null,
            "UnitPrice":"30.00000",
            "RatePercent":null,
            "PriceLevelRef":null,
            "MarkupInfo":null,
            "Qty":"1",
            "UOMRef":null,
            "ItemAccountRef":null,
            "InventorySiteRef":null,
            "TaxCodeRef":{  
               "name":null,
               "type":null,
               "value":2
            }
         },
         "DescriptionLineDetail":null,
         "ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail":null,
         "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail":null,
         "DepositLineDetail":null,
         "PurchaseOrderItemLineDetail":null,
         "ItemReceiptLineDetail":null,
         "JournalEntryLineDetail":null,
         "GroupLineDetail":null,
         "SubTotalLineDetail":null,
         "TDSLineDetail":null,
         "CustomField":null,
         "LineEx":null
      },
      {  
         "Id":4,
         "LineNum":4,
         "Description":"Shipping Cost",
         "Amount":"3.29167",
         "LinkedTxn":null,
         "DetailType":"SalesItemLineDetail",
         "PaymentLineDetail":null,
         "DiscountLineDetail":null,
         "TaxLineDetail":null,
         "SalesItemLineDetail":{  
            "ServiceDate":null,
            "TaxInclusiveAmt":null,
            "DiscountRate":null,
            "DiscountAmt":null,
            "SalesItemLineDetailEx":null,
            "ItemRef":{  
               "name":"Shipping Cost",
               "type":null,
               "value":"1"
            },
            "ClassRef":null,
            "UnitPrice":"3.29167",
            "RatePercent":null,
            "PriceLevelRef":null,
            "MarkupInfo":null,
            "Qty":"1",
            "UOMRef":null,
            "ItemAccountRef":null,
            "InventorySiteRef":null,
            "TaxCodeRef":{  
               "name":null,
               "type":null,
               "value":2
            }
         },
         "DescriptionLineDetail":null,
         "ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail":null,
         "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail":null,
         "DepositLineDetail":null,
         "PurchaseOrderItemLineDetail":null,
         "ItemReceiptLineDetail":null,
         "JournalEntryLineDetail":null,
         "GroupLineDetail":null,
         "SubTotalLineDetail":null,
         "TDSLineDetail":null,
         "CustomField":null,
         "LineEx":null
      }
   ],
   "TxnTaxDetail":null,
   "TxnSource":null,
   "TaxFormType":null,
   "TaxFormNum":null,
   "TransactionLocationType":null,
   "Id":null,
   "SyncToken":null,
   "MetaData":null,
   "CustomField":null,
   "AttachableRef":null,
   "domain":null,
   "status":null,
   "sparse":null
}
```

Could anyone suggest, what is actual problem with this request?

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates exactly what the problem is:

```
        "Message": "Invalid Reference Id",
        "Detail": "Invalid Reference Id : Line.SalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef",
        "code": "2500",
        "element": "Line.SalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef"
```

Based on your request, it looks like you're just inventing these values, rather than actually querying these from QuickBooks.

I'm assuming this because in one place your item is called one thing, and in another it's called something totally different:

```
"ItemRef":{  
               "name":"Shipping Cost",
               "type":null,
               "value":"1"
            },
```

Even though the `Id` `value`s are identical (1) in both cases:

```
"ItemRef":{  
               "name":"Additional Delivery Charge",
               "type":null,
               "value":"1"
            },
```

You can't just invent these numbers. They are `Id` values that you have to query from Intuit.

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/item

Query them by doing:

```
SELECT * FROM Item
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to submit an invoice line item with an ID outside the range of available IDs in the QuickBooks Sandbox.

For example, my production app has ~50 categories and the Sandbox only has ~20, so trying to use ID `40` in the Sandbox caused this error.

To resolve the issue I simply reduced the ID number for testing.